# MVC 'create user' method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

At the moment, I have the need to register a new user, and at the same time, create an 'account portfolio' record, and then assign him to that portfolio.

So, 3 database writes.

I have a Twitter-Bootstrap UI, using MVC4, which then goes to a Service, Logic and then Data access layer, which uses Entity Framework 5 to save to SQL Server.

At the moment, when the user clicks 'Register', I create a 'User' data transfer object, which basically has details about the user. I then create a 'Portfolio' object, which just has 'Description' and 'Id'. I have created a service method in my 'User' service class called 'RegisterNewUserWithPortfolio'. It takes the two objects. It then calls a Logic service class method in my UserLogic, with the same name and parameters.

It then calls a 'Save' method in the UserData class, passing it the UserDto, which gets back the new Id of the User it just saved.

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

It then calls the Save method in the AccountPortfolioData class, passing it the PortfolioDto, which is saved, and again, returns the Id.

I then call a method in the UserData class called 'AssignUserToPortfolio', taking the UserId, and the PortfolioId... and that then gets saved.

I now have a new user, linked to a Portfolio.

I can't do that in a EF Transaction, because I am calling different Data saving classes (As each of my entities has it's own class, to help keep them apart and easier to manage).

First, am I doing this right? Is there a better way?
And if so, is there a way I can put the whole group of calls into a transaction?

Note, my Dto objects are just custom, dumb objects used to pass the data between the layers. I am also not passing EF models to the UI. I am trying to keep it all layered and separated.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear, but from what I uderstand the easiest way would to map ER relationships for your User and Portfolio class

Thus

```
Public class User{

//
//
//
 public virtual ICollection<Portfolio> Portfolios
}

Public Class Portfolio{
//
public int UserId{get; set;}

[ForeignKey("UserId")
public virtual User user{get; set}
}
```

Entity Framework would automatically map the relationships. Hope this gets you started.